# Deleting duplicate value in View from the Base table

Tags: oracle, plsql

BASIC INFO : I have a table : YARDI_PROPERTY -> PK -> HMY, and a VIEW which uses HMY from it.

Issue : Getting duplicate HMY in the view.

Requirement : TO delete those duplicates.

IMPLEMENTATION :

```
DELETE FROM ODS.YARDI_PROPERTY WHERE HMY IN (select hmy, count(*)
from ODS.VW_YARDI_DLR_PROPERTY_INFORMATION DPI
group by hmy having count(*)>1 );
```

ERROR: Too many values.

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: Your subselect returns two columns ("Too many values") while the `IN` predicate only expects one.

Comment: @mustaccio solution ?

Comment: If there are two (or more) rows with same hmy do you want to delete them all or leave one?

Comment: It would also help if you provided the `CREATE VIEW` code.

Comment: i want to delete all the hmy  that have count greater than 1, i.e, duplicates and as view code is huge , i will host it on this link . :::->  https://collabedit.com/brnpd

Answer (score 1):

As @mustaccio helpfully pointed out in the comments you have too many columns returned in your subselect.

You don't have to specify the count(*) to use it in the having clause.

You can edit your subselect to something like:

```
DELETE FROM ODS.YARDI_PROPERTY WHERE HMY IN 
(select hmy
from ODS.VW_YARDI_DLR_PROPERTY_INFORMATION
group by hmy having count(*)>1 );
```

That will still find values of HMY that occur more than once in the table, but will return only one column, HMY, so won't cause an error in your DELETE statement.

Comment: But it will DELETE all of those rows with same value. The OP may not want this.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ ahh good point.  I am not sure exactly what the OP is trying to achieve with the question worded as is. At a glance I assumed OP was trying to delete from source, but I think OP might be trying to eliminate the duplicates only from the view.

Comment: Oh yeah, true. He may want to delete from the base table or just modify the view so it shows only one of the duplicates (or none). Needs clarification.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ agree. I see you asked for more details. Thx. I don't have the rep to comment yet.

It seems like OP wants to delete duplicates from the view which I assume is being caused in the code to create the view and would probably be most easily fixed there. HMY should already be unique in the underlying table for the view as it's the PK. 

I think we need more information about what is creating the view to help OP.

Comment: I think you can comment now ;)

Comment: hi guys thank you for answering and to resolve the doubt -> i want the duplicates present in view to be gone, and the table from which HMY comes is present as PK so no duplicates there, what worries me is , to avoid this from happening  again should i delete from the base table or THE view itself. @ypercubeᵀᴹ